# lists and divs and how to make them align beside/underneath each other

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```css
.date {
  float: left;
  border: 1px white solid;
  text-align: left;
}

.text {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 7px;
/*    color: white; */ /* Removed for the snippet */
  border: 1px white solid;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <ol>
    <div class="date">
      <span>Feb 24 1955</span>
    </div>
    <div class="text">Steven Paul was born in San Francisco, the son of Abdulfattah Jandali and Joanne Schieble. He is quickly adopted by Paul and Clara Jobs
    </div>
  </ol>
  <ol>
    <div class="date">
      <span>1969</span>
    </div>
    <div class="text">Steve Jobs meets Steve Wozniak, 5 years older, through a mutual friend. Woz and Steve share a love of electronics, Bob Dylan, and pranks
    </div>
  </ol>

  <ol>
    <div class="date">
      <span>1974</span>
    </div>
    <div class="text">Steve gets his first job at video game maker Atari, and later makes a trip to India to 'seek enlightenment' with his college friend Dan Kottke
    </div>
  </ol>

  <ol>
    <div class="date">
      <span>April 1 1976</span>
    </div>
    <div class="text">Apple Computer Inc. is incorporated by Steve Jobs, Steve Wozniak and Ron Wayne
    </div>
  </ol>
```

And I want the display to show up as (without the bullet points)

- Date       Text
- Date       Text

But right now it's showing as `Date Text Date Text`

I think if I didn't use `div` and instead only used `ol` it might work, but I want to practice using `div` and understand how positioning works in CSS.

Comment: You might wanna consider a table instead. If it's table data :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, replace `ol` with `li`. `ol` means an ordered list while `li` means list-item. Don't mix-up the two. `ul` and `ol` must contain `li`.

For your problem, I suggest a flex-box solution:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  margin:  5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.date {
  width: 25%;
  align-self: center;
}

.text {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="date">
      <span>Feb 24 1955</span>
    </div>
    <div class="text">Steven Paul was born in San Francisco, the son of Abdulfattah Jandali and Joanne Schieble. He is quickly adopted by Paul and Clara Jobs
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="date">
      <span>1969</span>
    </div>
    <div class="text">Steve Jobs meets Steve Wozniak, 5 years lider, through a mutual friend. Woz and Steve share a love of electronics, Bob Dylan, and pranks
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="date">
      <span>1974</span>
    </div>
    <div class="text">Steve gets his first job at video game maker Atari, and later makes a trip to India to 'seek enlightenment' with his clilege friend Dan Kottke
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="date">
      <span>April 1 1976</span>
    </div>
    <div class="text">Apple Computer Inc. is incorporated by Steve Jobs, Steve Wozniak and Ron Wayne
    </div>
  </li>
```

Comment: wow that's really cool! just quick questions... 1. does it matter if it's `ol` or `li` and 2. If i wanted to make the `text` at the middle of `date` do i simply increase `margin-bottom` for the `text`?

Comment: yes, ol and li are different things. `ul` mean  unordered list (no numbers) and `ol` mean ordered list (numbered). Both must contain `li` which mean list item.  Just search for HTML lists for more details. For 2 , what do you mean by text at the middle of date? Vertically center content?

Comment: Ah I see! thank you! What i mean by #2 is I want the text a little higher so that if the text is more than 1 sentence, the text would adjust so that the date is on the middle of the sentences. Like in Microsoft word, if you have a table you can align by top, center, or bottom. And in this case, I want to show as center. Hope this makes sense...

Comment: That's awesome! yes! is it the `align-self:center` ? that makes that?

Comment: Yes. You could also apply `align-items: center` to `li` instead. Read further about flex-box to understand in detail about the differences

Answer (score 0):

You only need to float `.date`, then `.text` will wrap around it. Your HTML is invalid though. a `ul` can't have an `ol` as a direct child. That should be a `li` instead.

```css
.date {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 1em 0 0;
}

li {
  margin: 0 0 1em;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
      <div class="date">
        <span>Feb 24 1955</span>
      </div>
      <div class="text">Steven Paul was born in San Francisco, the son of Abdulfattah Jandali and Joanne Schieble. He is quickly adopted by Paul and Clara Jobs
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="date">
        <span>1969</span>
      </div>
      <div class="text">Steve Jobs meets Steve Wozniak, 5 years older, through a mutual friend. Woz and Steve share a love of electronics, Bob Dylan, and pranks
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="date">
        <span>1974</span>
      </div>
      <div class="text">Steve gets his first job at video game maker Atari, and later makes a trip to India to 'seek enlightenment' with his college friend Dan Kottke
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="date">
        <span>April 1 1976</span>
      </div>
      <div class="text">Apple Computer Inc. is incorporated by Steve Jobs, Steve Wozniak and Ron Wayne
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```